# openjdk6 not available

Tags: installation, 10.04, server, java, openjdk

I run a server with Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) Minimal Server, on amd64 system. I 'd like to install the openjdk packages (jre and jdk), but when I try

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

I get

```
Package openjdk-6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package openjdk-6-jdk has no installation candidate
```

And I 'd like to install this package andI don't know how, while it seems to be available [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/openjdk-6-jdk)

Comment: (1) Do you have lucid main in your sources.list? Run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and provide the output in your question. (2) What do you mean by "minimal" server? Did you use the official server image (ubuntu-10.04*-server-*.iso) from http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ ?

Comment: Did you try a `sudo apt-get update` after changing your software mirrors?

Comment: Ok I tried apt-get clean and apt-get update and it worked. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try a `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update` after changing your software mirrors :)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and try these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa  
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Answer (score 0):

the error says "the package ....or is only available from another source"

Check your sources.list, see if it contains a non-standard ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has stop providing oracle 6 and 7 jdk. And to install older version, need to use offline installation method.

First download `oracle-jdk7-installer.tar.gz` and 
`oracle-java7-installer_7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1_all.deb`

```
cp -r oracle-jdk7-installer.tar.gz oracle-java7-installer_7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1_all.deb /var/cache/
cd /var/cache
tar -xvf oracle-jdk7-installer.tar.gz
dpkg -i oracle-java7-installer_7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1_all.deb
```